# Class can't have constants of own type inside?

Tags: c++, constexpr, incomplete-type

What I mean, is it possible to somehow do something like this?

```
class Color {
public:
    static constexpr Color BLACK = {0, 0, 0};

    constexpr Color(int r, int g, int b) : r_(r), g_(g), b_(b) {}

private:
    int r_;
    int g_;
    int b_;
};
```

Compilers complain about class `Color` being incomplete when defining `BLACK` constant.

Comment: It is a form of circular dependency. What if the constructor uses the Black constant? Can't you just define Black outside of the class?

Comment: For defining it out of class, you must lose the `constexpr` (it can still be `const`). But I don't think there's any other solution.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: `constexpr` can be moved outside [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d1TP9rs55).

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might move definition outside:

```
class Color {
public:
    static const Color BLACK;

    constexpr Color(int r, int g, int b) : r_(r), g_(g), b_(b) {}

private:
    int r_;
    int g_;
    int b_;
};
constexpr Color Color::BLACK = {0, 0, 0};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d1TP9rs55)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can change the static variable to a function call:

```
class Color {
public:
    static constexpr Color BLACK() { return {0, 0, 0}; }

    constexpr Color(int r, int g, int b) : r_(r), g_(g), b_(b) {}

private:
    int r_;
    int g_;
    int b_;
};
```